# jQuery plugin events

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery

I'm a bit confused over jQuery terminology for what I'm trying to accomplish.

Essentially I have a jQuery plugin that takes around 5 seconds from instantiation to being usable.  I want to expose an onReady event so the user can take action (like making a button visible) when the plugin is ready.

Something as simple as this:

```
$.test({

  exampleOption: "foo",

  onReady: function(event) {
    console.log("I'm ready to use!");
  }
});
```

I don't want to trigger any events or expose them or anything, I want the user to be able to specify a function to execute when the plugin internally triggers its 'onReady' event.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Joseph Just an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to is validate the delegate and call it from within your plugin:

```
if(options.onReady && typeof options.onReady === 'function'){
    options.onReady();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dana... so really, onReady is just a variable which is set to be a function and (after checking that it is), we just run that variable to execute the value of it (ie. the function).

Answer (score 0):

you pass the plugin a function:

```
$('element').myPlugin({
    ...options...
    onStart:function(){
        alert('foo?');
    }
});
```

then you your init block in your plugin (i can't create an exact plugin structure because it's different for everyone), just call the function and it will execute whatever was defined in the function body.

```
plugin.options.onStart()
```